# Microsoft Graph API end point GET : /calendarView?startDateTime={DateTime}&endDateTime={DateTime} returns 404 Not Found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I am trying to retrieve Calendar View for a user using end point GET : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserEmail}/calendarView?startDateTime=2020-09-25T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-10-02T19:00:00-08:00](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUserEmail%7D/calendarView?startDateTime=2020-09-25T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-10-02T19:00:00-08:00) and it returns

`{

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-10-23T15:11:51",
        "request-id": "20409ad4-2f27-48bd-8fe8-690580ccd4e9"
    }
}
```

}`

This is happening only for some users on our client environment.
Initially we thought, its an issue related to Permissions OR Access Token but both looks fine like user has all the permissions to read/write calendar and Access Token also looks valid too as some other end points which gives valid result with same access token.

So I tried Investigating it further more and found, if user has an exception type of Event on his outlook calendar then only /CalendarView end point returns 404.

For Example : This particular User has Exception type of Event on his calendar on Date 10/01/2020. So if I query Graph with same end point with different date range like GET : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/calendarView?startDateTime=2020-09-25T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-09-29T19:00:00-08:00](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bemail%7D/calendarView?startDateTime=2020-09-25T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-09-29T19:00:00-08:00) it works fine and it gives all the events between date ranges but if I change the endDateTime = 2020-10-02T19:00:00-08:00 it gives 404 response.

To validate this I tried to switch different end point
**GET : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/calendar/events?$filter=start/datetime](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bemail%7D/calendar/events?$filter=start/datetime) ge '2020-10-01' and end/dateTime lt '2020-10-02'**
Which works fine like it gives me the series Master Event

So I thought to use instances end point **GET : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserEmail}/events/{EventId}/instances?startDateTime=2020-09-29T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-10-26T19:00:00-08:00](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUserEmail%7D/events/%7BEventId%7D/instances?startDateTime=2020-09-29T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-10-26T19:00:00-08:00)** to get all the instances of the Series Master Event but surprisingly it fails to return Exception type of event from this end point too. [According to their documentation it supposed to return Occurrences and Exception of Series Master](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but for this user it only returns all Occurrence type of Event and failed to return Exception type of event which is on 10/01.

After that I tried one more end point POST : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule and found that specific event scheduled on his calendar.

but it only gives some information about the event.

Does any one knows how to solve this?

Comment: (1) Share the detailed response logs that you got (timestamp, requestid, error info). (2) In case if you see issue only with exception, then i would try the following API call like, "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AAMkAGUzYRgWAAA=/instances?startDateTime=2020-10-08T09:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2020-10-30T09:00:00.0000000&$select=subject,bodyPreview,seriesMasterId,type,recurrence,start,end". The above will gets within the specified time range the occurrences and exceptions of an event which is the master event of a recurring series. Try this and let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, yes we still need help with this issue

Comment: @Dev As I mentioned in my question, we already tried GET : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserEmail}/events/{EventId}/instances?startDateTime=2020-09-29T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2020-10-26T19:00:00-08:00 end point and it only returns Occurrence Type of event and skips Exception type of event in response